# Why does Guava's MapMaker report an incorrect size for my map when using weak keys?

Tags: java, guava

It's possible this is the expected behavior, but I can't find any documentation that says so.  I'm using Guava `14.0.1`.  In the below example, entries in the map that don't have a strong reference to the key get removed, which is what I expect, but the size of the map gets out of sync.

In the first check, both the size and count are 5.  However, in the second check the size is reported as 5, but the count is 0.  Why does the second check report the map size as 5 when there aren't actually any entries in the map?

```java
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.collect.MapMaker;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapSizeCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        keepReferencesAndCheckSize();
        System.out.println();
        discardReferencesAndCheckSize();
    }

    private static void keepReferencesAndCheckSize() {
        Map<Object,Object> map = new MapMaker().weakKeys().makeMap();
        List<Object> refs = Lists.newArrayList();

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            Object key = new Object();
            Object value = new Object();

            map.put(key, value);
            refs.add(key); // Hold a strong reference to the key.
        }

        System.gc();

        int size = map.size();
        int count = 0;

        Iterator<Object> it = map.keySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            count++;
            it.next();
        }

        System.out.println("Size  : " + size);
        System.out.println("Count : " + count);
    }

    private static void discardReferencesAndCheckSize() {
        Map<Object,Object> map = new MapMaker().weakKeys().makeMap();

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            Object key = new Object();
            Object value = new Object();

            map.put(key, value);
        }

        System.gc();

        int size = map.size();
        int count = 0;

        Iterator<Object> it = map.keySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            count++;
            it.next();
        }

        System.out.println("Size  : " + size);
        System.out.println("Count : " + count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior, but it's not made as explicit in `MapMaker`'s docs as it could be.  It is, however, consistent with [`CacheBuilder`'s docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html):

> If weakKeys, weakValues, or softValues are requested, it is possible for a key or value present in the cache to be reclaimed by the garbage collector. Entries with reclaimed keys or values may be removed from the cache on each cache modification, on occasional cache accesses, or on calls to Cache.cleanUp(); **such entries may be counted in Cache.size(), but will never be visible to read or write operations.**

...as well as the [JDK's own `WeakHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html#size%28%29):

> `public int size()`
>
> Returns the number of key-value mappings in this map. **This result is a snapshot, and may not reflect unprocessed entries that will be removed before next attempted access because they are no longer referenced.**

Comment: (The Javadocs for MapMaker have been revised to reflect this: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/detail?r=3d1299c5d302b7242d70103c1fc015b2baaf5776)